# UIActivityIndicator in Swift: how do you start and end it?

Tags: swift, uiactivityindicatorview

I am trying to do something like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myActivityMonitor: UIActivityIndicatorView!


func doStuff(){
   myActivityMonitor.startAnimating()

   //stuff running here

   myActivityMonitor.stopAnimating()
}
```

but it is not starting nor stopping in sync. Basically if I remove the stop it will look like it is always running after having done the computation that I need. the part inside the comment involves downloading an image from an HTML link.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running networking calls, they're usually ran asynchronously meaning that the task is handed off to another thread and completed there. The issue with this is it doesn't wait until the task is finished to stop animating causing `myActivityMonitor` to start and end almost at the same time.

To fix this, simply ensure that `myActivityMonitor` is accessible outside of the `doStuff` method and call `myActivityMonitor.stopAnimating()` elsewhere; preferably in a delegate method telling you that your data has finished loading.

Comment: Hi! do you mean something like:

    func doMoreStuff(){
       myActivityMonitor.startAnimating()
      
       doStuff()
   }

Comment: sorry I meant func doMoreStuff(){doStuff()  myActivityMonitor.stopAnimating()}

Comment: Not exactly. http://apple.co/1EBL789

This delegate can be used to determine when the data has finished loading (assuming you're using NSURLConnection). It's also where you can call `myActivityMonitor.stopAnimating()`

Comment: What about if I am not using NSURLConnection() ? Is there a more general way to sync the code? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I have figured out a way around it! I am gonna post it. You were spot on about not being in sync.

Comment: You might also be interested in this class: https://github.com/goktugyil/CozyLoadingActivity